# Yelp API latitude longitude

Tags: javascript, jquery, yelp

I am trying to use Yelp's API with a latitude/longitude location.  I used the javascript code that yelp gave out, which basically has a parameter array, and pushes values into it like so:

```
parameters.push(['term', terms]);
parameters.push(['location', near]);
parameters.push(['oauth_consumer_key', auth.consumerKey]);
```

On Yelp's documentation, it explains the call for latitude/longitude as 
    "ll=latitude,longitude,accuracy,altitude,altitude_accuracy"
  with only latitude and longitude being the required values.

When I try to use the following code, however, only the latitude gets pushed into the array and Yelp returns a Bad Request error:

```
parameters.push(['ll', latitude, longitude]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

They are looking for ("ll=lat,lon"), however your push is ("ll",lat,lon). Change it to ("ll=lat,lon"). i.e. ll=37.788022,-122.399797

Comment: lat and lon are variables though, and by doing that, you are simply passing the string 'll=lat,lon' rather than the actual values of the variables lat and lon

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this before, but is this assuming 11 is for latitude and longitude, or do you need to call it in separate procedures. I ask only from looking at the prior arguments, and assume they have a separate entity for each parameter. Though, I have not looked at their API. I will do so, then come back to this. :)

Comment: Here is the link to the documentation

http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api